# Trouble Toggling between two divs when a link is clicked - Javascript

Tags: dom, toggle

I'm currently trying to work on a basic JavaScript application.

I ultimately want to have a book that shows basic information on it's cover and with the click of a link, the book will show additional information.

I have two divs; #frontBook which will displays the front of the book which includes basic information about the current Book (i.e. Title, Author, Pages, Read or not) and #insideBook which will display additional info about the book(i.e. what page they're up to, publisher's name, etc.)

I want the #frontBook div to show and #insideBook to be hidden at first. Then once #additional-info link has been clicked, I want #frontBook to be hidden and #insideBook to be shown.

I've added my code below but it does not work. I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong. Please Help!

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I  know that JQuery would be recommended for something like this but I just want to make sure I can grasp this concept with JavaScript first.

HTML:

```
<div id="frontBook">
        <div id="book-outline">



            <div id="book-content">

                <ul id="basic-book-content">
                    <li><span class="basic-book-details" id="new-title">Title: </span></li>
                    <li><span class="basic-book-details" id="new-author">Author: </span></li>
                    <li><span class="basic-book-details" id="new-pages">Pages: </span></li>
                    <li><span class="basic-book-details" id="new-read">Read?:</span></li>
                    <li style="line-height: 80px; margin-right:-2px;">
                        <a href="#" id="additional-info" onclick="toggle_book();">Additional Info
                        <i style="color:white;" class="far fa-caret-square-right" ></i>
                    </a>

                    </li>
                </ul>


            </div>
            <!-- closes #book-content-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="insideBook" style="display:none">
        <div id="inside-book-outline">



            <div id="inside-book-content">

                <ul id="additional-book-content">
                    <li><span class="additional-book-details" id="new-editor"> Editor's Name: </span></li>
                    <li><span class="additional-book-details" id="new-publisher">Publisher's Name: </span></li>
                    <li><span class="additional-book-details" id="new-pub-comp">Publsiher Company's Name: </span></li>
                    <li><span class="additional-book-details" id="new-page-at">Page Up to:</span></li>
                    <li><span class="additional-book-details" id="new-line-at">Line Up to:</span></li>
                    <li><span class="additional-book-details" id="new-genre">Genre:</span></li>
                    <li><span class="additional-book-details" id="new-in-series">In Series?:</span></li>
                    <li style="line-height: 80px; margin-right:-2px;">
                        <a href="#" id="less-info" onclick="toggle_book();">
                        <i style="color:white;" class="far fa-caret-square-right"></i>Less Info
                    </a>

                    </li>

                </ul>


            </div>
            <!-- closes #inside-book-content-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle_book() {
    var front = document.getElementById('frontBook');
    var inside = document.getElementById('insideBook');
    if (inside.style.display === 'block') {
        inside.style.display = 'none';
        front.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        inside.style.display = 'block';
        front.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you seemed to have missed two things.

1)  You're `if` statement logic is backwards it should be:

```
function toggle_book() {
  var front = document.getElementById('frontBook');
  var inside = document.getElementById('insideBook');
  if (inside.style.display === 'block') {
    inside.style.display = 'none';
    front.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    inside.style.display = 'block';
    front.style.display = 'none';
  }
```

2) You don't have a `onclick` attribute for the `<a>` tag in the insideBook to toggle it back

Comment: Okay, I added a onclick attribute to the <a> tag that was missing it. I changed the if statement to what you suggested, however it's still not working. I'm also still not 100% sure why front.style.display is equal to 'none' and not 'block' after the else statement. Thank you

Comment: My mistake `front.style.display = 'none';` should be `front.style.display = 'block';`
It's been a long day.

Comment: Haha no worries! So if that's the case, then my original if statement was correct?

Comment: I've edited my answer to a working function. As you can see now, your function was backwards. The updated code should work. See, if the inside is visible, you want to hide it, otherwise, you want to show it and hide the front

Comment: I see that you edited your code. Is it still not working?

Comment: Okay thank you for editing your answer. I edited my question as well so you can see that I've updated the code. It's still not working. When I use the inspect tool with google chrome, when I click on the <a> tag with the onclick attribute, it says the function toggle_box is not defined.

Comment: How are you linking the Javascript to your HTML?